# WTForms SelectField with 'Are you sure" on change that can rollback

Tags: javascript, html

I have a SelectField in a Flask form that I want to add confirm to so user has to think before just saving a change. My attempt below does throw up the confirm box but that in itself does not do anything in that clicking YES or NO just returns me to page with new value displayed.

```
<p>
Change out Unit to new serial: {{ form.selectserial(data_toggle="tooltip", title="Select serial from System account!", onChange="return confirm('WARNING - Are you sure? This will change serial permanently!')")}}
</p>
```

I would like to return the selection to the default value ( before user changed it) if the user clicks No in Confirm box.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove that javascript handler from python code, and added to a script tag:

```
const selectSerial = document.querySelector('[name=selectserial]');
selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
// do whatever you want 

})
```